# How can I context switch between child and parent process continuosly?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am trying to write a program in C based on the concept of shared memory. I am creating two shared memory and creating two processes using the fork() function. I want one of the process to write into one of the shared memory and the other to read from it and vice versa with the other shared memory. I don't want to use pipes. How can i context switch between the two processes continuosly so that I can read from one and write from the other?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? If the two processes have to exchange data, they should probably access the same shared memory.

Comment: p1 must write in sm1 and p2 must read from sm1

Comment: p2 writes in sm2 and p1 reads from sm2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to write a program in C based on the concept of shared
>   memory. I am creating two shared memory and creating two processes
>   using the fork() function. I want one of the process to write into one
>   of the shared memory and the other to read from it and vice versa with
>   the other shared memory. I don't want to use pipes. How can i context
>   switch between the two processes continuosly so that I can read from
>   one and write from the other?

Context switching is not a C concept.  The OS manages it, outside the control of userspace programs.  But that might not even be relevant to your problem, because multicore and multiprocessor computers are the norm these days, and they can provide true concurrency, without context switching.

It is entirely possible for two processes to communicate via shared memory.  That's what it's *for*, after all.  But it is not possible for them to do so without a mechanism for synchronizing their actions.  For example, how is process B supposed to know when process A has finished updating the shared memory, so that B can read what A wrote?  And how can A know that B has finished reading so that no data will be lost if it updates the shared memory again?

These kinds of synchronization problems are handled via for-purpose synchronization objects such as semaphores, mutexes, and condition variables, and functions that operate on them.  How to use these properly is much too broad a topic to cover in one SO answer, but you will find many examples in various SO questions about the details.

Or you can just use pipes, which are a lot easier for communications that are fundamentally serial in nature.

Comment: As an aside, shared memory breaks the process sandbox and should be avoided unless there are strong performance reasons for doing so.